# Start chrome and send JavaScript code

Tags: c#, google-chrome

When you type `javascript:window.open('http://stackoverflow.com')` in chrome's navigation bar, it opens new tab. I want same, but when running chrome from cmd:

```
var process = Process.Start("chrome.exe",
    "javascript:window.open('http://stackoverflow.com')");
```

I'm doing this because I want to close that window later from inside it with `window.close()`. If I open website directly, error is thrown:

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
```

Comment: I also want to close tab from inside my angular application.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want chrome to open a new tab to a page, why not try:

```
var process = Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://stackoverflow.com");
```

If you just want to close the window later with JS, what about:

```
    window.open(location, '_self', '');
    window.close();
```

Note, you cannot automatically add the javascript prefix to a chrome URL, even with copy and paste - this is a security feature.

see - [Javascript stripped from URL bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698009/javascript-stripped-from-url-bar)

Comment: No, I want to run script.