# Execute Javascript code in browser via xJavascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for how to execute javascript code in the URL bar via xJavascript.

The standard way would be `xJavascript:JAVASCRIPTCODEHERE`, you would remove the "x" and it would execute the code, but that is not working.

Am I doing it wrong, or is no longer possible?

Please help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "xJavascript", I've never heard of that. Why would you type `x` only to immediately remove it afterwards? Just directly type the `javascript:…` url! Of course, [you may not copy-paste it, as browsers try to prevent self-xss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698009/why-is-javascript-pseudo-protocol-stripped-from-url-bar-when-pasted).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what browser you are on but this is what I use:

`javascript: (() => {  document.title = "Hello World";})();`

It also might not be working because you are running it on a new tab (which doesn't work for chrome)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this feature frequirently, make a bookmark with `javascript:...` code.

If you want to run some random JS while editing this JS, use Devtools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I in browser), Sources tab on top, Snippets tab on left. Snippets are persistent, editable, may run on any page.

If you want to run the same code on every page of a website, try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld or Tampermonkey